# How to verify certificate in SignedXml against machine store

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, signedxml

I would like to verify the signature in a `SignedXml` against the certificates in the machine store. This code is used to verify the signature:

```
internal bool VerifySignature(XmlDocument xml)
{
    var signedXml = new SignedXml(xml);
    var nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
    nsMgr.AddNamespace("ds", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");
    signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)xml.SelectSingleNode("//ds:Signature", nsMgr));
    return signedXml.CheckSignature();
}
```

The signature verifies fine, but only against itself and not against the certificates installed on the machine. Is there a way to check it against the root certificates in the local certificate store as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I used the `CheckSignature(X509Certificate2, Boolean)` method. I got the certificate from the `Signature` object and checked it like this:

```
var x509data = signedXml.Signature.KeyInfo.OfType<KeyInfoX509Data>().First();
var verified = false;
if(x509data != null)
{
    var cert = x509data.Certificates[0] as X509Certificate2;
    verified = cert != null && signedXml.CheckSignature(cert, false);
}
return verified;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the overload of the CheckSignature method which takes an AsymmetricAlgorithm.

Pass along the public key of your certificate. You can fetch this via X509Store.

Comment: That could probably work too, but as I don't know beforehand which certificate to use, I would have to get it from the `SignedXml` anyway and using `CheckSignature(X509Certificate2, Boolean)` instead there's no need to mess with the store. Thanks anyway though.